# function creation as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, function

I have tried asking this on specialty forums, and no one answers this for me, But I am hoping someone here can. Below is the snippet of code in question, and I know how it all works except for 2 bits of it.

```
this.data = allItems().filter(function(item) {
    return this.includes(item);
}, this);
```

As stated above, I understand all but two bits of the code above: What is this type of function called? a call back? There is no function called "item" or a variable within the main function called "item". Lastly, why is "this" a part of the snippet?

Sorry if this isn't enough information, I am trying to be as thorough as I can with this question as I am not familiar with this style of scripting. I have done some research on this subject, and the closest explanation as I can get is a private function, but as I mentioned above, there is no function called "item" anywhere.

Comment: `item` is just a declared parameter, like in every other function.

Comment: If you want to find out what `this` refers to, check [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) of the method that calls the callback.

Comment: `item` could be any other name.. It just refers to each element when filtering

Comment: Thanks for that Bergi and user6188402. I think I understand it now...knowing that "item" is simply a made up variable (and not THE variable, "item" [that variable would be an object, and crucial to the script as a whole]) made me realize what the heck was going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript is a bit of a strange language. For those of us that learned a compiled programming language first, it shares a visual aesthetic but the behind-the-scenes are very different.The first thing to understand is that in javascript every function as a special reference called `this`. It references the current iteration of the function.

Think of it like this: there is a class called `Human`, which defines a set of properties common to all humans -- we have a height and weight, a name, eye color, hair color, etc. But me, being 5'8", 200 lbs, hazel eyed, and bald is not the same description as you, or any other human being. While there could definitely be another human with those characteristics, we are not the same.

```
var Human = function(name, height, weight, eye_color) {
  this.name = name;
  this.height = height;
  this.weight = weight;
  this.eye_color = eye_color;
}

var me = new Human('Jhecht', '5.8', 200, 'hazel');
alert(me.name); //Alerts 'Jhecht'
var you = new Human('Gatene', '6.0', 190, 'brown');
alert(you.name); //Alerts 'Gatene'
```

The `this` in the code ensures that the variables `me` and `you` mark us as individuals. This way, even though we can both have things in common, it is understood that we are not the same. It also makes it so that you can check on that information later. Without the `this` I would just be setting each variable equal to itself (`name=name`) which gives me ***no way*** to look at its contents later. If I removed the `this.name` and replaced it with `name`, I would no longer get my expected result if I tried to call `alert(me.name)`(I would most likely get an undefined value) When used on event listeners for HTML elements, `this` will refer to the HTML element, unless you tell it otherwise.

Functions in javascript are also a little less rigid (and I don't feel like that's the correct word, but it's the best one I've got) than functions in other languages. Notice in my code above I set my function like so:

```
var Human = function(name, height, weight, eye_color) ...
```

I could have also created that function like so:

```
function Human(name, height, weight, eye_color)...
```

and the outcome would be the same.

So in your code snippet, let's go through line by line.

```
this.data = allItems().filter(function(item) {
    return this.includes(item);
}, this);
```

1. `this.data` is saying "the data variable on `this` instance of the function call this code is from" is equal to `allItems()` which presumably returns an array of items, is filtered down by a function. Since Javascript allows for something called 'anonymous' functions, aka functions without a name, we create an anonymous function (non-named function) which accepts a named argument of `item`.
2. the function being passed to the .`filter` method in line 1 will return the result of the `includes` method (most likely defined somewhere previously in your code), which was being passed the value of our argument from line 1, `item`.
3. Ends the function definition with `}`. the next portion goes back to what I said before, `this` refers to the current function call, **unless** you instruct it not to. the `, this);` is the programmer saying "on this function, which I declared above, I want `this` to refer to the object I am using currently."

This part is tricky, and it will definitely take some time to understand so if you're not entirely sure don't worry too much about it.

Comment: *"[`this`] references the current iteration of [every] function"* - Err, no, as a general statement that's nonsense. `this` refers to any arbitrary value; which in particular is determined by a few rules, and usually it's the "context object".

Comment: That's how I've always used it, can you provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: Functions in general don't "iterate", and what is "an iteration" anyway that the `this` would refer to? That's what I mean by *nonsensical*.

Comment: functions don't iterate in terms of loops, but iterations are repetitions of something, an anonymous function called from another function is just a tad repetitious

Comment: What if it's only called once? And what is "the iteration" in practical terms, `typeof this == 'iteration'`...? Nope...

Comment: it seems to be we are at a lexical impasse.

Comment: I understood what Jhecht meant (thank you Jhecht), deceze. Jhecht was referring to the function I presented. Although I already knew what "this" meant, I didn't know that it was referencing the iteration of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the description you sent, Jhecht. I understand it completely now. The entire function that I didn't include in my snippet is based entirely off of item manipulation, and the variable "item" is an object that was passed around to many different functions except for the function that my snippet was a part of...so when the anonymous function threw in the "item" parameter, I was pulling my hair out (figuratively, I'm bald too) trying to figure it all out.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` function accepts a parameter. It is expected that this parameter will be a function with at least 1 parameters (`item`)

Your code snippet is passing an anonymous function as this parameter:

```
function(item) {
    return this.includes(item);
}
```

thus fulfilling the expectations of the `filter` function

Comment: Thanks Jasonscript. I have never heard of anonymous functions...that was throwing me off, making more questions...confusing me. I was thinking that "item" was either a parameter for the nameless function, or it was the name of the function. So, do anonymous functions have a "this" at the end? or is this script just binding the anonymous function to the function that filter() is a part of? Either way, I know I have more research to do on anonymous functions.

Answer (score 1):

> What is this type of function called? a call back?

It's an anonymous function (because it has no name), which is being passed as an argument to `filter`, and yes, it could be and is called a callback.

> There is no function called "item" or a variable within the main function called "item".

You're misunderstanding basic function syntax. `function(item)` does not refer to anything called `item`, a function or otherwise. It is defining an anonymous function with `item` as its single formal parameter.

> Lastly, why is "this" a part of the snippet?

Read the documentation for `filter`, and in particular the `thisArg` parameter, the second parameter, which specifies the value to use as `this` when the callback function is called. In this case, `this` is being specified, which is the `this` of the surrounding context, which is the same object which holds the property `data`, as well as the method known as `includes`.

It could be more easily written without using the `thisArg` parameter by using arrow functions, as

```
this.data = allItems().filter(item => this.includes(item));
```

Comment: Thank you torazaburo, but the last line you mentioned would have confused me even more. The scripter had an object variable "item" so, when I came across this - not fully understanding how filter actually worked - I was taken aback. I completely understand the code now. These shorthand scripting techniques take up less space, bu they will be the death of me.